# Javascript Email Special Validation

Tags: javascript, email-validation

I am trying to do some validation on an email field, however I have some "special" requirements, basically it has to act very similar to Outlook when you insert email addresses.

So my test scenarios are these:-

1. `test@test.com test1@test.com` -- should be invalid
2. `;; ; J,Smith<jsmith@mail.com>` -- should remove the ;; ; and keep the Name and email address and valid
3. `J,Smith<jsmith@mail.com> J,Smith<jsmith@mail.com>` -- should be invalid since there is no ';' in between
4. `J,Smith<jsmith@mail.com>; J,Smith<jsmith@mail.com>` -- should be valid
5. `J,Smith<jsmith@mail.com>;J,Smith<jsmith@mail.com>` -- should also be valid

So I came up with the "basic" RegEx

```
const _validEmail = new RegExp(/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/);
```

Which is working fine when validating the email address.

However I need something to also check the DisplayName and Email address together, and its also important to check wether there is a semicolon between them too, since that is what makes it valid.  And if there is only a whitespace, then its invalid.

Comment: Ok managed to come up with the regex that will determine if I have multiple emails in a string, however I am still after a regex that will also include the Display Name apart from the email, to determine multiple emails in the string

Comment: Regex for multiple emails is this :- (([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+)))(([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*;\s*|\s*$))+

Comment: I did a quick fix to split by '@' on the string after splitting by ';' and if the array is bigger than 2 it fails, however I would love to find a Regex that can do this more 'elegantly'!